# What interval is optimal? - Disabling Wp-Cron and Running Cron Job

Tags: wordpress, cron

Currently I have disabled wp-cron using wp-config file (after researching online and seeing that it seems even Wordpress recommends doing this) and then set up an cron job in cpanel using: 0,30   *   *   *   *   wget -q -O - https://www.sitehere.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1

Is 30 minutes really safe though? I'm thinking of changing it to 5 minutes or maybe 15 minutes but I don't know if that is resource heavy? Is there a downside to doing 5 minutes or even 15 minutes. I see our host recommends 30 minutes but I don't know if that is risky for any reason (i.e. we use WP-Rocket which I think uses cron to purge and preload cache). We don't use many server resources since we use Wp-Rocket, Cloudflare, MaxCDN, etc so I'm not sure if that would help make 5 minutes safe/better.

Any opinions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using traditional WP Cron will cause tasks to queue up until it's triggered on page load, so you can potentially have a bunch of tasks queued up.

The nature of your site will determine the optimal setting for you. 30 minutes seems a bit long (and is probably an overcautious safe-guard to prevent extraneous cron jobs running every second across multiple users).

10-15 minutes is typically a better starting point, but if you have tasks that need updated more often, you're almost certainly okay having it run every 5 minutes, or even every minute if your server will support it. Keep in mind it won't really do anything unless there are tasks queued up to be run!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm thinking of trying 5 minutes since as you described it there seems to be no downside technically since it would only run if there is something scheduled. It is SiteGround so I'm hoping the 30 minutes isn't a forced requirement and just a recommendation. I will test it at 5 minutes I'm thinking and see.